# How many threads are used by default in TParallel::For?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, parallel.for

I want to use `TParallel::For` in C++ Builder, but would like to know how many threads are used by default in this loop? For example, if I have 1000 iterations that can be done in parallel, will they be executed by creating 1000 threads all at once, or the maximum number of threads at any time is limited by the number of logical processors?

My point is - I don't want to have `TParallel::For` creating more threads at once then the CPU supports. So, if CPU supports 8 threads will those iterations be executed 8 by 8 until all 1000 iterations are executed, or will there be created 1000 threads all at once?

Comment: It uses the default thread pool, unless you provide your own thread pool. There is, at least these days, quite extensive documentation. I'd start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default pool handler looks for both the computer resources and the load of the computer.

From [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_the_Parallel_Programming_Library) (emphasis mine):

> The RTL provides the Parallel Programming Library (PPL), giving your applications the ability to have tasks running in parallel taking advantage of working across multiple CPU devices and computers. The PPL includes a number of advanced features for running tasks, joining tasks, waiting on groups of tasks, etc. to process. For all this, **there is a thread pool that self tunes itself automatically (based on the load on the CPU’s) so you do not have to care about creating or managing threads for this purpose.**

If you want to take control over the pooling, you can [define your own pool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TParallel.For):

> When APool parameter of type TThreadPool is specified, the program author controls the thread resources available to the iterated events of TParallel.For through the use of its TThreadPool.SetMinWorkerThreads and TThreadPool.SetMaxWorkerThreads methods. Be advised when calling these methods that too many simultaneous threads can generate overhead that diminishes or eliminates the benefit of executing routines in parallel.

---

The default threadpool is initialized with following limits:

```
FMinLimitWorkerThreadCount := TThread.ProcessorCount;
FMaxLimitWorkerThreadCount := TThread.ProcessorCount * MaxThreadsPerCPU;
```

`MaxThreadsPerCPU` is a constant set to 25. So, based on the processor load, the used threads in the pool is varied between those numbers.

Comment: I will accept this answer, but I also found the following on Stephen's Ball blog: "Defined in System.Threading, TThreadPool initiates with a default of 25 threads per CPU."